# Dynamic Date in where clause

Tags: sql-server

The following statement is working fine

```
select * from tblLibrary where returnDate < {ts '2014-03-21 15:06:05.300'}
```

But when I replace **'2014-03-21 15:06:05.300'** with **GETDATE()** the function is not working.

Any suggestion

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not working how? Error, unexpected/no results?

Comment: gives me following error "Msg 155, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
'ts' is not a recognized ODBC scalar function option."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from tblLibrary where returnDate < GETDATE()
```

or

```
DECLARE @DATE smalldatetime;
Select  @DATE = GETDATE();
select * from tblLibrary where returnDate < @DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

`{ts '2014-03-21 15:06:05.300'}` is an [ODBC escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for specifying a timestamp *value*. It has a very rigid grammar, and can *only* be used to specify a value. You can't combine such a sequence with e.g. built in functions. `{ts GETDATE()}` doesn't work.

But it's not clear why you're trying to combine the two - you can just specify `GETDATE()` without needing to use the escape syntax.

```
select * from tblLibrary where returnDate < GETDATE()
```